# Android: Свайп вверх

Tags: android, java

В оф. приложении ВК новости обновляются тапаньем экрана вверх (свайпом вверх, если можно так выразиться). Нечто такое и в некоторых браузерах.

Вопрос такой:

Как сделать такое и показывать, например, editText с кнопкой?

Comment: тап - это быстрое касание, а свайп - это жест пролистывания.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это работает широко известная в узких кругах библиотека [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh).

Автор [Chris Banes](http://chris.banes.me/)

Comment: По примерам из библиотеки, как я понял, можно только обновлять другие виджеты.
А можно ли создать кнопку с edit'ом при свайпинге вверх?

Comment: Не пробовал, но кастомизации наверное поддается. При свайпе там появляется ожидалка/крутилка - почему бы не прикрутить туда `EditText`? Правда зачем - загадка. Обычно используется по другому - при свайпе запускается фоновый процесс обновления списка - я использовал именно так.